# Accessing JSON with HandleBars

Tags: arrays, json, handlebars.js, frontend

I have this JSON:

```
{
  {
  "status": {
    "success": true,
    "error": ""
  },
  "data": {
    "hello_world": [
      {
        "uid": {
          "email": "mydx@d.com",
          "id": "d3c074d8b2b24e958"
        },
        "my_itm": {
          "name": "BIg",
          "id": "2380caa99cb426f"
        },
        "id": "6747e005f23f451"
      },
      {
        "uid": {
          "email": "mydx@d.com",
           "id": "5859082d3c074d8b2b24e958"
        },
        "my_itm": {
          "name": "Dog",
          "id": "a99cb426f"
        },
        "id": "c6747e005f23f452"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm using handlebars and I want to access from `my_itm` the name. But I want to do that `foreach my_itm`. How can I do that?

Here is what I've tried:

```
{{#each hello_world.my_itm}}
  <p>{{name}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED:**

Assuming you passed the data to the template under the 'params' name:

```
res.render('test', {params: <your data>})
```

You can do this:

```
{{#each params.data.hello_world}}
            {{#if my_itm}}
                    {{my_itm.name}} <br>
            {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Gives:

```
BIg 
Dog
```

What you have didn't work because hello_world is an array and not an object with a my_itm property you can access directly, you need to loop through the array first.

**PS:** You also seem to have an extra { in the json.